# File Upload: Why does this code works in a controller and not in another?

Tags: laravel

There are 2 forms that take string and file input, in one controller the strings and the file are properly sent and upload in the specified folder, in the second however the file is not upload even though they use the same code except for the name of the variable for the file:
Inside demandePCController.php

```
if($request->hasFile('situation')){
            $image=$request->file('situation');
            $count = count(Storage::files('situation'));
            $prefix='PC-';
            $image_name=$prefix.($count+1).'.'.$image->extension();
            Storage::put("situation/{$image_name}",file_get_contents($request->file('situation')->getRealPath()));
        }
```

Inside demandePC.blade.php:

```
<div>
                                <x-label for="situation" :value="__('Situation Juridique')" />
                                <x-input id="situation" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="file" name="situation"/>
                            </div>
```

Inside demandeALController.php

```
if($request->hasFile('cin')){
            $image=$request->file('cin');
            $count=count(Storage::files('cin'));
            $prefix="AL-";
            $image_name=$prefix.($count+1).".".$image->extension();
            Storage::put("cin/{$image_name}",file_get_contents($request->file('cin')->getRealPath()));
        }
```

Inside the demandeAL.blade.php

```
<div>    
                                <x-label for="cin" :value="__('CIN demandeur')"/>
                                <x-input id="cin" class="inline mt-1 w-full" type="file" name="cin"/>
                                
                            </div>
```

I tried to modify the code for the same result but to no avail, the logic is perfect, so why does it not work as intended?

Comment: Please share the form code that each controller has

Comment: Are the forms the same? Both have an `enctype`?

Comment: You need to share the `<form>` or javascritp triggering an AJAX call...

Comment: they are different forms, and do not have an enctype

Comment: if they don't have `enctype`  then you will never be able to upload files to the controller to handle...

Comment: From the PHP manual on [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php): "_Note: Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work. _"

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put an enctype, the problem is solved, thank you everybody